# Detect Bluetooth device connect/disconnect in background using core bluetooth in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth, background-mode

I need to programmatically detect the connect and disconnect event of any bluetooth device with iPhone, while app is in background.

Comment: If you mean accessory devices, such as handsfree, audio speakers etc then the answer is you can't. If you mean BLE peripheral's then your app can manage its own connections but doesn't know anything about any other apps connections.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm targeting Bluetooth Audio Speakers

Comment: In that case you may be able to use route change monitoring https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges.html but you will only get a notification in the background if you have an active audio session in background mode.